# AWS Organizations "You have exceeded the allowed number of AWS accounts"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

When trying to create a new account in my Organization, I get the following message:

[image]

I have a total of 3 accounts under my Organization, including the Management Account.

```bash
$ aws organizations list-accounts | jq '.Accounts | length'
3
```

Organizations limits & quotas [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_reference_limits.html#min-max-values) tells me the default limit is **10**:

> 10 — The default maximum number of accounts allowed in an organization.

I also have no account invitations that would take space in the count, what would be the reason for this message?

[image]

**Update**

Service quotas is not counting the number of accounts. Utilization field says "Not available":

[image]

If I force quota request to 10 for example, it says that it must be greater than the current value.

If my limit is 10, but I have only 3 accounts created, than why is it blocking creation on the Organizations blade?

[image]

**Update 2**

To add to my CLI evidence, I only have 3 accounts created.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like something to ask AWS Customer Service (which is different to Customer Support).

Comment: Did you checked the status in service quotas of us-east-1?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra if you mean the Trusted Advisor, I checked it and it seems to not keep track of the number of accounts in an Organization, am I right?

Comment: No i am talking about checking the service quotas for aws organization https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home?region=us-east-1#!/services/organizations/quotas, you can default quota value and utilized quota value just to confirm

Comment: @JatinMehrotra check my update, it's not counting that specific quota.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I didn't understand your comment. I should have 7 slots available as I only have 3 accounts created. I do not need a quota increase, rather I need to know why is my quota blocking at 3 when there's (should be) actually 7 available (see my updates)

Comment: I am suggesting that you ask AWS, since it seems like a problem related to your AWS Account rather than anything technical that you have done wrong. While AWS Customer Support is only available if you have an activate Support plan, you can always contact AWS Customer Service for account-related issues (eg quotas, reserved instances, payment problems).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein done. Will post something here if we solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was resolved by opening a ticket on Support Center and they fixed the problem.

Comment: same here, just opened a case and they fixed it